# How to perform CRUD operations in Marklogic Server?

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I want to do CRUD operations on xml docs stored in Marklogic Server. Can anybody tell me please how can I perform CRUD operations in Marklogic Server ?

Answer (score 1):

How are you connecting to the MarkLogic database?  This may make a big difference in how you go about doing CRUD.

If you are pushing data in using an HTTP service you can use an existing REST endpoint such as the [Corona project](https://github.com/marklogic/Corona) or make your own using XQuery.

If you are using Java or .Net you can connect through the XCC library, which have functions for CRUD without having to write XQuery.

In pure XQuery the following commands may be useful to read up on in the MarkLogic XQuery function documentation on the MarkLogic web site:

- [`xdmp:document-insert()`](http://community.marklogic.com/pubs/3.2/apidocs/UpdateBuiltins.html#document-insert)

  - this will do the Create and Update of CRUD
- `fn:doc-available()`

  - if you want to test to see if a document exists. Some people doing CRUD want this in order to make Create and Update different .  Other's don't care.
- [`xdmp:document-delete()`](http://community.marklogic.com/pubs/3.2/apidocs/UpdateBuiltins.html#document-delete)

  - the Delete in CRUD
- `fn:doc()`

  - the Read in CRUD

Answer (score 0):

Once the document is stored, you use functions like `xdmp:node-replace()`, `xdmp:node-insert-child()` etc. to manipulate the document node-by-node. Alternatively, you can change a document by saving a new version to the same URI via `xdmp:document-insert()`, or delete a document via `xdmp:document-delete()`.

Note that the transactional semantics in MarkLogic are truly functional, so the document never changes during execution of a transaction. You need to complete the transaction and get the document from the database to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

See also http://community.marklogic.com/try/corona/index for a higher-level API.